# Putting everything in its place

Tags: c#, meta-programming, roslyn

A new diagnostic has seen the light of day! This one will alert you when you have a `string.Format()` call where the formatting placeholders are in the wrong order. The right order is defined as:

> For each placeholder with index N, its value should be higher or equal to the placeholder at index N-1

If you want a more elaborate overview of what scenarios should be handled how you can take a look at the accompanying unit tests. I *think* I have covered all special scenarios in which placeholders can be used but since I get surprised by exotic scenarios all the time, please let me know if I forgot anything.

### Unit tests <sub>[Github](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/blob/develop/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics.Test/Tests/Strings/StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderTests.cs)</sub>

I omitted the tests because it would put my post way over the limited amount of characters.

### Analyzer <sub>[Github](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/blob/develop/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/Diagnostics/Strings/StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrder/StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderAnalyzer.cs)</sub>

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;

namespace VSDiagnostics.Diagnostics.Strings.StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrder
{
    [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    public class StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
    {
        private static readonly string Category = VSDiagnosticsResources.StringsCategory;
        private const string DiagnosticId = nameof(StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderAnalyzer);
        private static readonly string Message = VSDiagnosticsResources.StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderMessage;
        private const DiagnosticSeverity Severity = DiagnosticSeverity.Warning;
        private static readonly string Title = VSDiagnosticsResources.StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderTitle;

        internal static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule => new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, Message, Category, Severity, true);

        public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
        }

        private void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var invocation = context.Node as InvocationExpressionSyntax;
            if (invocation == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Verify we're dealing with a string.Format() call
            var memberAccessExpression = invocation.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
            if (memberAccessExpression != null)
            {
                var invokedType = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(memberAccessExpression.Expression);
                var invokedMethod = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(memberAccessExpression.Name);
                if (invokedType.Symbol == null || invokedMethod.Symbol == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (invokedType.Symbol.MetadataName != typeof(string).Name || invokedMethod.Symbol.MetadataName != nameof(string.Format))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Verify the format is a literal expression and not a method invocation or an identifier
            // The overloads are in the form string.Format(string, object[]) or string.Format(CultureInfo, string, object[])
            if (invocation.ArgumentList == null || invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments.Count < 2)
            {
                return;
            }

            var firstArgument = invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments[0];
            var secondArgument = invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments[1];

            var firstArgumentSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(firstArgument.Expression);
            if (!(firstArgument.Expression is LiteralExpressionSyntax) &&
                (firstArgumentSymbol.Symbol?.MetadataName == typeof(CultureInfo).Name && !(secondArgument?.Expression is LiteralExpressionSyntax)))
            {
                return;
            }

            // Get the formatted string from the correct position
            var firstArgumentIsLiteral = firstArgument.Expression is LiteralExpressionSyntax;
            var formatString = firstArgumentIsLiteral
                ? ((LiteralExpressionSyntax) firstArgument.Expression).GetText().ToString()
                : ((LiteralExpressionSyntax) secondArgument.Expression).GetText().ToString();

            // Verify that all placeholders are counting from low to high.
            // Not all placeholders have to be used necessarily, we only re-order the ones that are actually used in the format string.
            //
            // Display a warning when the integers in question are not in ascending or equal order. 
            var placeholders = StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderHelper.GetPlaceholders(formatString);

            // If there's no placeholder used or there's only one, there's nothing to re-order
            if (placeholders.Count <= 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            for (var index = 1; index < placeholders.Count; index++)
            {
                int firstValue, secondValue;
                if (!int.TryParse(StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderHelper.Normalize(placeholders[index - 1].Value), out firstValue) ||
                    !int.TryParse(StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderHelper.Normalize(placeholders[index].Value), out secondValue))
                {
                    // Parsing failed
                    return;
                }

                // Given a scenario like this:
                //     string.Format("{0} {1} {4} {3}", a, b, c, d)
                // it would otherwise crash because it's trying to access index 4, which we obviously don't have.
                var argumentsToSkip = firstArgumentIsLiteral ? 1 : 2;
                if (firstValue >= invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments.Count - argumentsToSkip || secondValue >= invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments.Count - argumentsToSkip)
                {
                    return;
                }

                // They should be in ascending or equal order
                if (firstValue > secondValue)
                {
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocation.GetLocation()));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Code Fix <sub>[Github](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/blob/develop/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/Diagnostics/Strings/StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrder/StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderCodeFix.cs)</sub>

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Composition;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeActions;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeFixes;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace VSDiagnostics.Diagnostics.Strings.StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrder
{
    [ExportCodeFixProvider("StringPlaceHoldersInWrongOrder", LanguageNames.CSharp), Shared]
    public class StringPlaceHoldersInWrongOrderCodeFix : CodeFixProvider
    {
        public override ImmutableArray<string> FixableDiagnosticIds => ImmutableArray.Create(StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderAnalyzer.Rule.Id);

        public override FixAllProvider GetFixAllProvider() => WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer;

        public override async Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
        {
            var root = await context.Document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var diagnostic = context.Diagnostics.First();
            var diagnosticSpan = diagnostic.Location.SourceSpan;

            var stringFormatInvocation = root.FindToken(diagnosticSpan.Start).Parent.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().First();
            context.RegisterCodeFix(
                CodeAction.Create(VSDiagnosticsResources.StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderCodeFixTitle, x => ReOrderPlaceholdersAsync(context.Document, root, stringFormatInvocation),
                    nameof(StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderAnalyzer)),
                diagnostic);
        }

        private static Task<Solution> ReOrderPlaceholdersAsync(Document document, SyntaxNode root, InvocationExpressionSyntax stringFormatInvocation)
        {
            var firstArgumentIsLiteral = stringFormatInvocation.ArgumentList.Arguments[0].Expression is LiteralExpressionSyntax;
            var formatString = ((LiteralExpressionSyntax) stringFormatInvocation.ArgumentList.Arguments[firstArgumentIsLiteral ? 0 : 1].Expression).GetText().ToString();
            var elements = StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderHelper.GetPlaceholdersSplit(formatString);
            var matches = StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderHelper.GetPlaceholders(formatString);

            // Here we will store a key-value pair of the old placeholder value and the new value that we associate with it
            var placeholderMapping = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            // This contains the order in which the placeholders appeared in the original format string.
            // For example if it had the string "{1} x {0} y {2} {2}" then this collection would contain the values 1-0-2.
            // You'll notice that we omitted the duplicate: we don't want to add an argument twice.
            // Typically we'd do this by using a HashSet<T> but since we can't easily retrieve an item from the HashSet<T>, 
            // we'll just check for duplicates upon inserting in the list.
            // Based on this we can then reconstruct the argument list by reordering the existing arguments.
            var placeholderIndexOrder = new List<int>();

            var amountOfPlaceholders = 0;
            var newPlaceholderValue = 0;

            var sb = new StringBuilder(elements.Length);
            for (var index = 0; index < elements.Length; index++)
            {
                // If it's a numerical value, it means we're dealing with a placeholder
                // Use Normalize() to account for formatted placeholders
                int placeholderValue;
                if (int.TryParse(StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderHelper.Normalize(elements[index]), out placeholderValue))
                {
                    // If we already have a new value associated with this placeholder, retrieve it and add it to our result
                    if (placeholderMapping.ContainsKey(placeholderValue))
                    {
                        sb.Append(GetNewElement(matches, amountOfPlaceholders, placeholderMapping[placeholderValue]));
                    }
                    else // Otherwise use the new placeholder value and store the mapping
                    {
                        sb.Append(GetNewElement(matches, amountOfPlaceholders, newPlaceholderValue));
                        placeholderMapping.Add(placeholderValue, newPlaceholderValue);
                        newPlaceholderValue++;
                    }

                    if (!placeholderIndexOrder.Contains(placeholderValue))
                    {
                        placeholderIndexOrder.Add(placeholderValue);
                    }

                    amountOfPlaceholders++;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(elements[index]);
                }
            }
            var newFormat = sb.ToString();

            // Create a new argument for the formatting string
            var newArgument = stringFormatInvocation.ArgumentList.Arguments[firstArgumentIsLiteral ? 0 : 1].WithExpression(SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression(newFormat));

            // Create a new list for the arguments which are injected in the formatting string
            // In order to do this we iterate over the mapping which is in essence a guideline that tells us which index
            IEnumerable<ArgumentSyntax> args = firstArgumentIsLiteral
                ? new[] { newArgument }
                : new[] { stringFormatInvocation.ArgumentList.Arguments[0], newArgument };

            // Skip the formatting literal and, if applicable, the formatprovider
            var argumentsToSkip = firstArgumentIsLiteral ? 1 : 2;
            for (var index = 0; index < placeholderIndexOrder.Count; index++)
            {
                args = args.Concat(new[] { stringFormatInvocation.ArgumentList.Arguments[placeholderIndexOrder[index] + argumentsToSkip] });
            }

            // If there are less arguments in the new list compared to the old one, it means there was an unused argument
            // In that case we will loop over all the old arguments, see if they're contained in the new list and if not: add them
            // Since the variables weren't used in the first place, we can add them in whatever order we want
            // However because we are traversing from the front, they will be added in the same order as they were anyway
            if (stringFormatInvocation.ArgumentList.Arguments.Count != args.Count())
            {
                foreach (var arg in stringFormatInvocation.ArgumentList.Arguments.Skip(argumentsToSkip))
                {
                    if (!args.Contains(arg))
                    {
                        args = args.Concat(new[] { arg });
                    }
                }
            }

            var newArguments = stringFormatInvocation.ArgumentList.WithArguments(SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(args));
            var newInvocation = stringFormatInvocation.WithArgumentList(newArguments);
            var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(stringFormatInvocation, newInvocation);
            var newDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
            return Task.FromResult(newDocument.Project.Solution);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Because the Regex.Split does not maintain any brackets or formatting, we have to now reconstruct the previous
        ///     placeholder but with a new index.
        /// </summary>
        private static string GetNewElement(MatchCollection matches, int oldPlaceholderIndex, int newPlaceholderValue)
        {
            var originalValue = matches[oldPlaceholderIndex].Value;
            var newValue = new StringBuilder();

            for (var index = 0; index < originalValue.Length; index++)
            {
                // Formatting detected: append everything remaining
                if (originalValue[index] == ':')
                {
                    newValue.Append(originalValue.Substring(index));
                    return newValue.ToString();
                }

                // Closing brace detected: append the remaining closing brace(s)
                if (originalValue[index] == '}')
                {
                    newValue.Append(originalValue.Substring(index));
                    return newValue.ToString();
                }

                // Opening brace detected: just add it
                if (originalValue[index] == '{')
                {
                    newValue.Append(originalValue[index]);
                }
                else
                // If it's not a formatting delimiter or open- or closing braces, it must be the actual placeholder value.
                // Replace it by appending the new value.
                {
                    newValue.Append(newPlaceholderValue);
                }
            }
            return newValue.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

### Helper <sub>[Github](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/blob/develop/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/Diagnostics/Strings/StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrder/StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderHelper.cs)</sub>

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace VSDiagnostics.Diagnostics.Strings.StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrder
{
    internal static class StringPlaceholdersInWrongOrderHelper
    {
        private const string Pattern = @"(?<!\{)\{(?:\{\{)*(\d+(?::.*?)?)\}(?:\}\})*(?!\})";

        /// <summary>
        ///     Removes all curly braces and formatting definitions from the placeholder
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">The placeholder entry to parse.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns the placeholder index.</returns>
        internal static string Normalize(string input)
        {
            var temp = input.Trim('{', '}');
            var colonIndex = temp.IndexOf(':');
            if (colonIndex > 0)
            {
                return temp.Remove(colonIndex);
            }

            return temp;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Get all elements in a string that are enclosed by an uneven amount of curly brackets (to account for escaped
        ///     brackets).
        ///     The result will be elements that are either plain integers or integers with a format appended to it, delimited by a
        ///     colon.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">The format string with placeholders.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a collection of matches according to the regex.</returns>
        internal static MatchCollection GetPlaceholders(string input)
        {
            return Regex.Matches(input, Pattern);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns all elements from the input, split on the placeholders.
        ///     This method is useful if you want to make use of the rest of the string as well.
        /// </summary>
        internal static string[] GetPlaceholdersSplit(string input)
        {
            return Regex.Split(input, Pattern);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

> ```
> private const string Pattern = @"(?<!\{)\{(?:\{\{)*(\d+(?::.*?)?)\}(?:\}\})*(?!\})";
> ```

That pattern is the only reason you need a helper method like this:

> ```
> /// <returns>Returns the placeholder index.</returns>
> internal static string Normalize(string input)
> {
>     var temp = input.Trim('{', '}');
>     var colonIndex = temp.IndexOf(':');
>     if (colonIndex > 0)
>     {
>         return temp.Remove(colonIndex);
>     }
>
>     return temp;
> }
> ```

You could leverage named groups and, on top of a more readable regex, you get named match groups and zero string-manipulation work needed to figure out the placeholder index:

```
"(?<!\{)\{(?:\{\{)*((?<index>\d+)(?::.*?)?)\}(?:\}\})*(?!\})"
```

That's it! Your index is *given* to you as part of the match!

[image: regex validation results]

Answer (score 8):

While reading my code for the bazillionth time, I noticed a logical error which would make it possible for very specific exotic scenarios to pop this up expectedly.

At the very start of the analyzer there is a check to see whether or not we're dealing with a `string.Format()` call:

```
// Verify we're dealing with a string.Format() call
var memberAccessExpression = invocation.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
if (memberAccessExpression != null)
{
    var invokedType = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(memberAccessExpression.Expression);
    var invokedMethod = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(memberAccessExpression.Name);
    if (invokedType.Symbol == null || invokedMethod.Symbol == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (invokedType.Symbol.MetadataName != typeof(string).Name || invokedMethod.Symbol.MetadataName != nameof(string.Format))
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

What's relevant here is the general `if` statement:

```
var memberAccessExpression = invocation.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
if (memberAccessExpression != null)
{
}
```

Which begs the question: what if the invocation's expression is not of type `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax`?!

After some searching I found an example of an invocation that isn't like this: a simple method call! There the expression is simply an `IdentifierNameSyntax`.

To keep a long story short -- in order for us to report the diagnostic, we also have to adhere to the following restrictions:

#### Make sure there are at least 2 arguments

```
if (invocation.ArgumentList == null || invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments.Count < 2)
```

#### Make sure the first argument is a string literal

```
if (!(firstArgument.Expression is LiteralExpressionSyntax)
```

#### Make sure there are placeholders in the string

```
if (placeholders.Count <= 1)
```

#### Make sure the placeholders are in the wrong order

```
if (firstValue > secondValue)
```

---

Knowing all this, I tried my code with the following setup:

```
Program()
{
    MyMethod("{1}{0}", 2, 3);
}

void MyMethod(string x, int y, int z) { }
```

and most surely: it provides me with a warning and a fix (which works!) to swap the placeholders and the arguments.

---

The solution is easy: add an `else { return; }` to the first `if` statement.